# Publishing Code First Project to Cloud

Tags: azure, cloud, publishing

I do not know how to publish my code first project from Visual Studio 2012 to Azure cloud  as the publish method for the cloud is different compared to publishing to Azure  Web site. When I try to publish to Azure cloud, my database does not get created and initialized as it does when I publish to Azure web site.

How should I publish to cloud and make sure my database is created and seeded?

Answer (score -1):

There could be multiple things you would need to verify to make the code first working with SQL Database.

1. CodeFirst does works SQL Database however you must be using EF 4.3.1 or later if newer is available.
2. Please verify your connection string that it does connect to SQL DB and the user you specified does have full access to create different objects in your SQL database.
3. Be sure to have your connection string provider using System.Data.SqlClient

As you do have your same connection string working with Windows Azure Websites, so I believe it is the correct and could be used as it is.

[Added 12/20/2012]
In the package manager console, please execute Enable-Migrations" which will add necessary migration specific code.

Also in the publish dialog box, you should see "Execute Code First Migration" setting which should enable the migration when package will be deployed to server.

You would need to make necessary changed as described below:

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394698#efcfmigrations

If you do not see above setting, please read this SO discussion:

1. [Execute Code First Migrations is Grayed Out in Publish Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495792/execute-code-first-migrations-is-grayed-out-in-publish-settings)

[image]

Comment: My real issue is how to publish from Visual Studio to the cloud in a way that database gets created and seeded. I have all the above in place but the Publish method I have on my Cloud Project is no pushing the database to azure cloud. I have no issue if I publish to Azure web site as the publish mechanism is different.