# Database is missing in Web Deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple web application that I want to deploy my test environment on my local IIS.  I am following the guide below.

[ASP.NET Web Deployment using Visual Studio](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis)

I am stuck at the section where you have to set my database on the test environment.  I can't find my default connection and the checkbox 'Update Database'.  On the DbContext section, I am also not able to check the checkbox 'Execute Code First Migration ...' (screenshot below)

[image]
What did I do wrong?  I can't any articles about this.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?  The article says it works using Visual Studio 2010 or 2012.

Comment: @user89861 I am using Visual Studio Express 2013.

Answer (score 0):

There has been some problem with *code first migration* in visual studio 2013. 
Please refer to [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/811516/publish-dialog-never-shows-the-execute-code-first-migrations-checkbox) link.

> I've confirmed that VS2013 Update 2 is working as described in this problem. The reason people want the below behavior is to enable code first migrations in cloud (Deployed) scenarios.
>
> [Work Around]
>   Here is a way to accomplish Code First Migrations without the publish profile check boxes. 
>   http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-code-first-migrations/
>
> Expected
>   Settings section of publish profile would have database settings with a checkbox that allows me to enable code first migrations
>
> Actual
>   Settings section of publish profile doesn't have a database section
>
> Recreation
>
> 1. create new windows 8.1 installation
> 2. update all windows updates
> 3. install vs2013 with update 2 from MSDN subscriptions web installer, selected all installation options
> 4. install all updates
> 5. create mobile service project from cloud project templates
> 6. build
> 7. add publish profile for web deploy (tried azure, import, and custom)
> 8. select settings section and view available properties

You can alternately use the *Package Manager Console* for your migrations as described in the link above.

Also look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495792/execute-code-first-migrations-is-grayed-out-in-publish-settings) similar issue.