# Deployed ASp.net mvc app on Microsoft Azure doesnt deploy Database

Tags: c#, azure

while Publishing ASP.net MVC application on Azure , it runs successfully on Local PC but throws error "Error. An error occurred while processing your request", I fail to understand how to deploy local database along other deployment file. below is my web.config files:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!--
      For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
      http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
      -->
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
      </configSections>
      <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ApplicationDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Socialite-1314f36a-a98d-4721-b718-4bbf00b45edd;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Socialite-1314f36a-a98d-4721-b718-4bbf00b45edd.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
      </connectionStrings>
      <appSettings>
        <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
      </appSettings>
      <system.web>
        <authentication mode="None" />
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
      </system.web>
      <system.webServer>
        <modules>
          <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
        </modules>
      <handlers>
          <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
          <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
          <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
          <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
        </handlers></system.webServer>
      <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
      </runtime>
      <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
          <parameters>
            <parameter value="v11.0" />
          </parameters>
        </defaultConnectionFactory>
        <providers>
          <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        </providers>
      </entityFramework>
    </configuration>
```

Application DBContext

using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System.Data.Entity;

```
namespace Socialite.Models
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public DbSet<Gig> Gigs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Attendance> Attendances { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Following> Followings { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Notification> Notifications { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserNotification> UserNotifications { get; set; }

        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {

        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Attendance>()
                .HasRequired(a => a.Gig)
                .WithMany(g => g.Attendances)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .HasMany(u => u.Followers)
                .WithRequired(f => f.Followee)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .HasMany(u => u.Followees)
                .WithRequired(f => f.Follower)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<UserNotification>()
                .HasRequired(n => n.User)
                .WithMany(u => u.UserNotifications)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

Please help . this already wasted hours of productive time.

Thank you

Comment: Look at your connection string, it indicates you're accessing you a LOCAL database instance.

If you're deploying your application to an external environment you're going to want to expose your database to allow external connections or host your database in Azure.

Comment: Jeez! Please any lead how to go about that. Tx

Comment: First you need a database server, then change your connection to point to it? Simple as that

Answer (score 0):

You could use **Entity Framework Code First Migrations** to deploy your local database to azure along with your project.

If you are deploying your application to azure, Visual Studio can automate the process of deploying a database that is managed by Code First Migrations.You could check my steps.

1. Create [Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-portal) on azure portal
2. Go to visual studio, set the **Destination Connection String** of the database option in publish settings with your user name, password and server name
3. select the **Excute Code First Migrations(runs on application start)** option,if the option is disabled, you should enable the migration first,please refer to this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495792/execute-code-first-migrations-is-grayed-out-in-publish-settings/12503937).

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394698#Configuring%20Database%20Deployment%20in%20Visual%20Studio).